# Filename as legend in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Presently I am using the following script (using gnuplot)  to plot files whose names are `m_1, m_2, .. m_10`

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1300,850 enhanced font 'Verdana'
set output 'output_1-10.png'
set grid ytics lc rgb "#bbbbbb" lw 2 lt 1
set title "Energy along the vibrational modes (1 to 10)"
set xlabel "(n)*0.02 of displacement vector"
set ylabel "energy (Hartree)"
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
set format y "%f";
filename(n) = sprintf("m_%d", n)
plot for [i=1:10] filename(i) using 1:2 with linespoints lw 3
replot
```

[image]
In the plot, the legend shows as `filename(i) using 1:2`. Is it possible to instead show the filename like

`m_1`

`m_2`

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `title filename(i)` to set the legend for each file :

```
plot for [i=1:10] filename(i) using 1:2 with linespoints lw 3 title filename(i)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above mentioned answer. But it gave error. However, I also tried this `plot for [i=1:10] filename(i)  using 1:2 with linespoints lw 3 title filename(i)` and then it works.

Comment: Indeed sorry for that